# How to handle ajax errors on response.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a single page order form. The user fills our the form, javascript validates everything and if it passes an ajax request will hit the server and charge the customer via Stripe when they click submit.

If the charge is successful, json is returned to the ajax request (`{success:true}`). The user is then redirected to an success page, or an error is displayed if something happened when charging the card.

I'm trying to handle a (rare) issue where the user's request hits the server, the user is successfully charged, but on response the user receives an error (most likely a timeout error on mobile/unstable connection). How can I prevent a user from being double charged? Below is my ajax request, but maybe I need to rethink my entire infrastructure?

```
$.ajax({ type : 'POST',
url      : '/order',
data     : $(':input').serialize(),
timeout  : 30000,
dataType : 'json',
success : function (data) {

  // redirect user to success page
  window.location = '/completed';

},
error: function(xhr,status,error) {

  // report the error to user. 

} });
```

Comment: Doesn't Stripe send confirmation emails or something?

Comment: Are you handling anything on the backend? If you are you could have the error retry if it fails. If you are not handling the transaction, maybe set up a small backend app that this AJAX posts to, have that post to Stripe, and handle that possible error. EDIT: Also, how do you know this error is happening?

Comment: Display a message that there was a timeout and set a timeout to request the data again. Or you handle the double-charge on server-side (given that you have an id for every request)

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I am handlings the transaction on my server, if first does a couple checks like making sure we didn't sell out, then posts the charges to stripe and returns any errors. I know the error is happening, because a user is receiving an error (most likely ajax timeout) and then submitting again and being double charged.

Comment: @floatleft idk what kind of stack you are using, but if you know what the average response time is that is causing the error, you should be able to trigger your own response if that average response time is reached. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
type     : 'POST',
url      : '/order',
data     : $(':input').serialize(),
timeout  : 30000,
dataType : 'json',
success : function (data) {

  // redirect user to success page
  window.location = '/completed';

},
error: function(xhr,status,error) {

  if (xhr.status == 408) {//For Timeout
                alert("Sorry, Request timeout.!");
                window.location.href ="//specify a redirect url//";
            }
            else {
                alert("An error occurred: " + status + "nError: " + error);
            }

} });
```